# Running docker container of spring boot project, file declared in application.yml is not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, logback

At a spring boot application,
at application.yml I have defined a file path for the logback configuration. It is found and taken into account correctly when running the app.

```
logging:
  config: src/main/resources/config/logback-spring.xml
```

and when i run the created image i get the following error

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'src/main/resources/config/logback-spring.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/workspace/src/main/resources/config/logback-spring.xml (No such file or directory)                                                   at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

Docker runs the `/workspace/` path that messes up the build. (same happens if i run with docker run or with docker-compose up)

The app runs fine from maven or intellij or jar file.

What am I missing ? Addittional info can be provided if asked in the comments

Comment: There is no `src/main/resources` it is part of the classpath, remove it from the path.

Comment: Even if I put the logback-spring.xml to project root folder, and set at application.yml `config:  logback-spring.xml` again the docker cant find it, searching `/workspace/logback-spring.xml`

Comment: Please read. Leave the file where it is. Just change the path in the configuration. You might need `classpath:/config/logback-spring.xml` instead of plain `/config/logback-spring.xml`.

Comment: sorry i cant follow. I tried various things based on your answer but it fails. I am not questioning your answer, probably i didnt implement it correctly. I am not very experienced. Could you please write a detailed answer with exactly what I should write on the application.yml and the filestructure, thanks

Comment: @M.Deinum I overcame the problem by putting the logback xml at the resources folder without a config folder, so i dont have to define a file on the yml, it finds it automatically. 
My problem might be resolved, but still i have the question, if i need to define another file, how would it be done that docker  recognizes it? So I will leave the question open

Comment: I already told you how to. PUt your file in `src/main/resources/config/logback-spring.xml` then in your properties use `/config/logback-spring.xml` (although that is a file reference instead of classpath or `classpath:/config/logback-spring.xml`.

Comment: Hello, was this solved?